# Wordpress - get_template_part() section not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, html, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm loading a front-end site onto a html5blank wordpress theme. The header.php and footer.php files are working fine but my first get_template_part() section won't show up. I've looked through the template hierarchy and I can't see what could be causing the issue.

This is how I have my code -

**whatwedo.php**

```
<?php /* Template Name: whatwedo */ ?>

        <section id="what">
              <!-- whatwedo template code -->
         </section>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


        <!-- section -->
        <section>   

            <?php get_template_part('whatwedo'); ?>

        </section>
        <!-- /section -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**page-home.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part('whatwedo'); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm not sure whether the template name should go in index.php or page-home.php but either way it should show up shouldn't it? I only have two pages set up in the dashboard so far - home and blog - and I'm pretty sure they're set up correctly.

Can anyone see why this might be happening?

Comment: As long as the template file whatwedo.php is in the child or parent theme then it should find it.  I can't see any issues with your code...

Comment: @AndrewSchultz This is so frustrating. None of the templates are showing - it looks like they're there but I can't see them. Like I've got a default opacity rule somewhere that's hiding everything.

Comment: Can you check the browser source code to see if the template is there but being hidden by a CSS rule?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the `<?php /* Template Name: whatwedo */ ?>`. That's specifically for a template, not a template *part*.

That part creates a new template (which can be selected from the page editor in the admin section).